# How to display MemoryLogger on asp.NET ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I am using asp.NET Entity Framework to display run my web application and am wanting to display a log of tasks being completed in the background. The logging functionality is working I just need to display it on my ViewModel

Controller
[image: Controller]

View

[image: View]

I just dont understand what to add to the top section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving you an example of your scenario:

**Model:**
In a LOGS class

```
namespace Log.Models
{
    public class LOGS
    {

        public static List<ListOfLogs> lstLogs = new List<ListOfLogs>();
        public class ListOfLogs
        {
            public string log { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            Log.Models.LOGS.lstLogs = new List<Models.LOGS.ListOfLogs>();
            Models.LOGS.ListOfLogs inputlogs = new Models.LOGS.ListOfLogs();
            inputlogs.log = "This is your first log";

            Log.Models.LOGS.lstLogs.Add(inputlogs);

            inputlogs = new Models.LOGS.ListOfLogs();
            inputlogs.log = "This is your second log";

            Log.Models.LOGS.lstLogs.Add(inputlogs);

            return View();
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var m in Log.Models.LOGS.lstLogs)
            {
                <td>@m.log.ToString()</td>
            }

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Well done Good luck!